# R Shiny - How to show/hide "fileinput" based on condition (tab panel selection)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I need to show "fileinput"/file upload option when a particular tabpanel is selected.

Ex. There are 3 tabpanels like A,B and C

When tab B is selected the "fileinput" option should appear and when A or C is selected, the "fileinput" option should be hidden from the sidebarpanel.

I tried the below but not working. Can anyone help? Thanks...

```
sidebarPanel(
conditionalPanel(condition = "input$id == 'B'", fileInput("file", "Choose xlsx file", accept = ".xlsx"))

 mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("A", value = 'A', DT::dataTableOutput("Table A")),
            tabPanel("B", value = 'B', DT::dataTableOutput("Table B")),
            tabPanel("C", value = 'C', DT::dataTableOutput("Table C")),
            id ="tabselected"
          )
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the appropriate ID of the `tabsetPanel` in the condition with a `.` instead of `$`.  Try this

```
library(readxl)

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabselected == 'tab2'", 
                           fileInput("file", "Choose xlsx file", accept = ".xlsx")),
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'selected.indicator',
            label = 'Select an option: ',
            choices = colnames(mtcars)
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("A", value = 'tab1',  DTOutput("t1")),
            tabPanel("B", value = 'tab2',  DTOutput("t2")),
            tabPanel("C", value = 'tab3',  DTOutput("t3")),
            id ="tabselected"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$t1 <- renderDT(cars)
    output$t3 <- renderDT(mtcars)
    
    mydata <- reactive({
      req(input$file)
      inFile <- input$file
      
      df <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    })
    
    output$t2 <- renderDT({
      req(mydata())
      mydata()
    })
    
  }
))
```

Comment: I have posted few other questions as well. It would be great if you can help me on that too !!!